# empty file geodatabase error (nowhere feature class)using arcpy

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arc-hydro

i want to import a python(2.7) script to arcmap 10.1 my script  has 2 inputs variables one for workspace and another raster dataset and i want o convert input raster as feature class polygon .
i want to create a file geodatabase and import in her a export feature class,run this script and finaly show me **complete message(not error)**...
but created the basis is empty,nowhere feature class.my feature class=**Catchment**
and i want to import in **gdb**(my file geodatabase) but if i run this script show me complete message but the **gdb**(my file geodatabase) is empty

```
import arcpy
import sys
import os
from arcpy import env as e
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.ImportToolbox("C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Arc Hydro Tools.tbx", "archydrotools")
try:
 e.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) # import workspace
 Cat = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)         # import raster dataset
 ws = e.workspace
 gdb = "teleia"                            # import name of geodatabase
 # Local variables:
 arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
 arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
 arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(ws,gdb)
 out = ws + os.sep + gdb + os.sep
 # Process: Catchment Polygon Processing
 arcpy.CatchmentPolyProcessing_archydrotools(Cat, Catchment)
 Catchment =out + "Catchment"
except:
 arcpy.GetMessages()
```

any idea ?

Comment: There seems to be a lot of extra code in your script than what you need to accomplish according to the text of your stated aim in your Question.  Consequently, I recommend that you try to create a (largely) working snippet of Python code so that what you are asking becomes clearer.  To do this I think you should start with a new *.py and just copy into it the parts you need to "create a file geodatabase and import in her a export feature class".  Once you get this working then, and only then, would I advise starting to complicate it with additional code.

Comment: i edit my question

Comment: try with the ".gdb" extension on you gdb name

Comment: gdb = "teleia" + ".gdb" that is a right ?

Comment: thanx that right

Answer (score 2):

Still difficult to interpret your question but untested code below may help.

```
import arcpy
import os
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial") # only required if CatchmentPolyProcessing requires it
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Arc Hydro Tools.tbx", "archydrotools")

try:
    ws = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)      # workspace
    rasCat = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)  # raster dataset
    gdb = "teleia"                        # geodatabase name
    catchment = "Catchment"

    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(ws,gdb)
    outGDB = os.path.join(ws,gdb)

    # Process: Catchment Polygon Processing
    polyCat = os.path.join(outGDB, catchment)
    arcpy.AddMessage('CatchmentPolyProcessing inputs = \n\t%s\n\t%s' %(rasCat, polyCat))
    arcpy.CatchmentPolyProcessing_archydrotools(rasCat, polyCat)
    arcpy.AddMessage('Complete')
except:
    arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages())
```

Comment: look cat is a raster dataset and i want to convert to polygon and import that convert in file geodatabase.
1. step create a file geodatabase
2.step convert raster to polygon
3.step import that polygon in to file geodatabase

my proplem is can not to import that polygon feature class in file geodatabase,after the run file gedatabase is still empty...

and your code has same problem
after the run your code file geodatabase is empty